# Internal ads in my site for my users using DoubleClick or similar platforms

Tags: double-click, advertisement-server, double-click-advertising

I have a B2B website and I want my users to be able to publish ads in different pages in the site.

From my understanding, I can manage all my ad slots with adservers such as DoubleClick for Publishers.  On the other  hand I must manage my users ad campaigns with tools such as DoubleClick campaign manager which will generate all the ads that the adserver must distribute through my pages.

Can someone guide me and tell me if I'am wrong on my approach?

Answer (score 0):

DoubleClick for Publishers (DFP) is a publisher ad server. DFP lets you manage your ad units as a publisher, allowing you to set rules to sell your inventory directly to advertisers or to ad networks.

Advertisers can send the creatives over to you, so you can traffick them in DFP. However, they would normally have an advertiser ad server, and hand you the ad tags from this advertiser ad server instead. DoubleClick Campaign Manager (DCM) is an advertiser ad server that allows your advertisers to report on, manage, and traffick their advertising campaigns.